# Ordered arrangement of clouds

Tags: meteorology, clouds

I happened to take a photograph of a region of clouds ,and it seems to have a rather ordered arrangement ,if one looks towards the left of the image. Would there be a physical explanation for this or is it just chance?
[image]

Comment: density waves?  frothing sea waves often  display order

Comment: I was thinking about the physics aspect of things....If nothing comes by, might as well try Earth Science SE too

Comment: [cloud streets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horizontal_convective_rolls).

Comment: Yes, this looks like cloud streets due to convection rather than wave clouds ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_cloud )

Comment: Please take a look at this answer - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/what-causes-these-banded-clouds/4457#4457

Comment: Agreed, this is answered in the linked question, this photo is just a bit closer in compared to the example in the link.

Answer (score 2):

These are weakly formed gravity clouds or density clouds. Clouds are formed from condensation, which is just tiny water (and other gases) droplets and vapor. As such, these tiny droplets and vapors will flow like ripples on the surface of water in a slow breeze. What you're seeing here is light-action wave ripples in the atmosphere and the resulting effect on the tiny droplets, is a wave-like or ripple-like pattern.