# GOES image: parallel trains of clouds. What to make of them?

Tags: clouds, weather-satellites

[image]
Here is a GOES visible image from today, 2019-12-01 about local noon, around Nova Scotia. Note the parallel trains or streaks of clouds, running approximately northwest to southeast.

A few hours ago, the wind was from the NW at 30-40kph (at Halifax); for the past 3 hours it's been from the NNW at about 25kph.

What's the physics behind the streaking? Is it simply cumulus clouds from convection being blown downwind?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes theses banded clouds?](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4452/what-causes-these-banded-clouds)

Comment: It seems to be [Cirrostratus cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cirrostratus_cloud), like [those](https://www.google.com/search?q=cirrostratus&rlz=1C1GCEU_enKW853KW853&sxsrf=ACYBGNQka0IcefELzAMx53impLn3pE-RJA:1575279421580&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwixjuGS1ZbmAhWrx4UKHS-lAAcQ_AUoAXoECBAQAw&biw=1920&bih=888)

Answer (score 3):

The species is [Stratocumuls undulatus](https://cloudatlas.wmo.int/en/varieties-stratocumulus-undulatus-sc-un.html) Sc un.

They can form for example when cold, dry air moves over a warmer ground layer. A sharp wind shear at the boundary layer blows these waves. ([Wikipedia on Sc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratocumulus_cloud)).

They are not to be confused with [Sc radiatus](http://Stratocumulus%20radiatus) or yet another form, the so-called "cloud streets", which form along the wind direction.

Answer (score 0):

My wild guess would be windshear at a low level inversion. Cold calm air below, warm windy air above, with clouds forming at the inversion. Could be checked with a look at an atmospheric [sounding](http://weather.uwyo.edu/upperair/sounding.html) with wind, temperature and due point curve from the area and the time ...
[Cartoon](https://www.aviationweather.ws/046_Wind_Shear.php) for visuals